# Double request on the database when scrolling

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

this is the javascript that invokes the request when scrolling

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

        var tempScrollTop, currentScrollTop = 0; 
        $(document).scroll(function(){ 

        currentScrollTop = $(document).scrollTop(); 

        var ids = new Array();

    if (tempScrollTop < currentScrollTop ) 
    {
        var result = currentScrollTop % 100;
        if(result == 0)
        {
            //console.log('scroll happened');
            var items = $(".item");
            var items_l = items.length;
            for(var i = 0; i < items_l; i++)
            {
                ids[i] = parseInt(items[i].id.replace(/\D+/g,""));

            }
            ids = ids.sort();

            var last_id = ids[0];
            $.ajax({
              url: "ajax/load",
              type: "POST",
              data: {last_id : last_id},
              success: function(res){

              $("#content").append(res);

              }
            });
        }
    }
    /*else if (tempScrollTop > currentScrollTop ) 
    {
        var result = currentScrollTop % 100;
        if(result == 0)
        {
            $("#content").text("Вверх запрос " + result);
        }
    }*/

    tempScrollTop = currentScrollTop; 
    })


});
```

and this is the controller method:

```
public function ajaxLoad()
{
    $last_id = intval($this->input->post("last_id"));
    //$last_id++;
    $db_data['query'] = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id < ".$last_id." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('item', $db_data, true);
    echo $data['content'];
}
```

i have two questions:

1) how can i prevent from double request that sometimes makes 2 equal records to be outputed? when i scroll down

2) how can i make that every 100 pixels of scrolling the records are appending, but the problem is that is hard to make currentScrollTol % 100 == 0, how can i change it to normal??

Comment: for Q2 you might want to try "abs(tempScrollTop-currentScrollTop) >= 100" instead of the "% 100" hitting the scrollTop on an exact 100 boundary is hit and miss

Comment: yeah thanks for that post, but how about the first question, i changed the async to false, now is synchrous which block the browser for some time, its not good, how can i make the request asynchrous without double requests when scrolling??

Comment: could try just using an RequestInProgress boolean var to prevent a send post while first hasnt completed

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
   var tempScrollTop, currentScrollTop = 0, isLoading = false; 
   $(document).scroll(function(){
```

[...snip... ]

```
     var last_id = ids[0];
     if ( !isLoading ) {
        isLoading = true;
        $.ajax({
          url: "ajax/load",
          type: "POST",
          data: {last_id : last_id},
          success: function(res){

          $("#content").append(res);
          isLoading = false;
          },
          error: function() { isLoading = false; }  // just in case
        });
```

[... etc ...]

Of course this will only let you load one thing at a time but at least it won't lock up your UI.

You could also store the last_id value in a higher scope (kinda like the boolean) and use that to make sure that you are not loading the same thing again... Both of these methods have their flaws, but it might suit your needs.

-m1

Answer (score 0):

So you have two problems:

1) You don't always hit the %100 condition

2) You sometimes hit the %100 condition more than once

I would suggest something like:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var tempScrollTop, currentScrollTop = 0; 
        var loaded = {};
        loaded[0] = true; //assuming the first piece comes loaded
        $(document).scroll(function(){ 

            currentScrollTop = $(document).scrollTop(); 

            var ids = new Array();  

            //this gives you a different int value for each 100 px section
            //at 67px, you get 0, at 345px you get 3, etc
            int section = Math.floor(currentScrollTop/100)
            if(!loaded[section]) {
                //prevents double request
                loaded[section] = true;
                var items = $(".item");
                var items_l = items.length;
                for(var i = 0; i < items_l; i++)
                {
                    ids[i] = parseInt(items[i].id.replace(/\D+/g,""));
                }
                ids = ids.sort();

                var last_id = ids[0];
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax/load",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {last_id : last_id},
                    success: function(res){
                        $("#content").append(res);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

I would also note that any of these solutions, including the original, will have some issues if you reload after scrolling down a bit, as the browser will jump down to the point you scrolled to without calling the scroll events to generate the page that is above that point.  But that's outside the scope of the question.